# PHP retrieve session value on drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using session storage with drop down list, I need to get retrieve session values on drop down list. I have given below to follow my code. Please help me anyone

```
 <td align="left" width="50%" valign="top" class="bordeau2">
        <select name="numFormCand" id="numFormCand" class="saisie" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['numFormCand'];?>"  autofocus >
        <option value="-1" >Choisissez</option>
        <option id="" value="apple"  title="apple">apple</option>
        <option id="numFormCand" value="orange">orange</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: What exactly are you storing in the session? The selected value, or all available options? For the first one, you'll need to use the `Selected`  attribute : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: I need to retrieve selected value

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selected` html attribute : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```
<select name="numFormCand" id="numFormCand" class="saisie" tabindex="1" autofocus >
    <option value="-1">Choisissez</option>
    <option id="" value="apple" title="apple"<?php if ($_SESSION['numFormCand'] == 'apple') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>apple</option>
    <option id="numFormCand" value="orange"<?php if ($_SESSION['numFormCand'] == 'orange') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
session_start();

?>
<select id="session_list" class="session_list">
    <?php
if ($_SESSION) {
    foreach ($_SESSION as $session_id => $session_value) {

        echo '<option value="' . $session_id . '">' . $session_value . '</option>';
    }

} else {
    echo '<option></option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: This can have a potential security risk, as all data, including potentially sensitive data stored in the session will be displayed on user facing page.